# Selenium RC: Not able to Click on Microsoft Dynamics CRM Pannel link. Navigation

Tags: selenium, crm

> com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: ERROR: Command execution
>   failure. Please search the user group at
>   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/selenium-users for error
>   details from the log window.

The error message is: `can't access dead object`:

```
selenium.click( "//*[@id='navTabLogoTextId']") 
selenium.clickAt("//*[@id='navTabLogoTextId']")
```

see the image **http://s1.postimg.org/ogdw8qdjj/image.gif**

Comment: Kindly check the link. Contain the image. http://s1.postimg.org/ogdw8qdjj/image.gif

Comment: Whats the HTML code of that section?